# best way to update RAMDirectory

Tags: java, lucene

At inconsistent intervals, specific documents in a Lucene index need to be updated.  The updates could be hourly or every few minutes.  Currently I have a process that runs and looks for changes, and if changes have happened, it (in Lucene 3.5 fashion) removes the document and then re-adds it to the RAMDirectory.

1. Is there a better way to manage a Lucene index of documents that are constantly transforming?  Is RAMDirectory the best choice?

The code I use for "updating" the index:

```
Term idTerm = new Term("uid",row.getKey());
getWriter().deleteDocuments(idTerm);
getWriter().commit();
// do some fun stuff creating a new doc with the changes
getWriter().addDocument(doc);
```

Comment: Must the documents be searchable after every update to the document? The easiest way, without having to change much, would be to delay updating the documents until a fixed interval--say every hour--and then do you it a batch pass and accumulate all the updates between times X and Y. That would reduce some of the performance overhead from deleting every couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene has recently had two very useful helper classes to handle frequently-changing indexes:

- [SearcherManager](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/SearcherManager.html),
- [NRTManager](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/NRTManager.html).

You can read more about them at [Mike McCandless' blog](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/11/near-real-time-readers-with-lucenes.html).